# how to load a streamstring from a char* which has binary data in hexadecimal represetantion?

Tags: c++, c

I usually work in C, but now I am using a library in C++ that it is useful to compress and uncompress data. Then I have my compress data in a char array. Just like:

```
strg[40] = "400000000200000002000200000000ffffff80";
```

From there I need to load a stringstream variable with the binary data that is represented by this array. Someone can help me please?

Comment: How does the data in the string affect what the stringstream will represent? Won't they both just represent the same (opaque) string of characters?

Comment: You can convert every two digits into a byte (e.g. via a lookup table), one byte at a time.

Comment: This don't sound like a good compression library :)

Answer (score 2):

Kerrek's comment is spot on.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
const char *p = strg;
if (p) while (*p) {
    unsigned char x = hex2int(*p) << 4;
    if (*++p) x |= hex2int(*p++);
    ss << x;
}
```

But this assumes big endian representation of the input stream. If the input stream is actually representing multi-byte words with little endian representation, you'll have to change the translation.